# How to perform multiple updates to a table in bigquery on google cloud platform?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I wish to rewrite the values for a text column in a table I have.  The particular field has entries like "cat", "dog", "mouse", etc.  I wish to rewrite the values in this field as "dog" or "not_a_dog"

Currently I have a query, with commented out portions. I un-comment a line, run it. Comment it back and then un-comment the next line, run it. etc.

I'm sure there is a way to do this programatically.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
UPDATE some_dataset.some_table SET label='not_a_dog' WHERE label='cat'
#UPDATE some_dataset.some_table SET label='not_a_dog' WHERE label='mouse'
#UPDATE some_dataset.some_table SET label='not_a_dog' WHERE label='moose'
```

Note I am using standard SQL in BigQuery. I tried playing with a stored procedure but I am not sure if my failure was because I don't really know stored procedures or if they are not compatible with standard SQL in BigQuery on Google Cloud Platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an IN list:

```
UPDATE some_dataset.some_table
SET label='not_a_dog' WHERE label IN ('cat', 'mouse', 'moose')
```

Comment: That was incredibly simple and concise.  Many thanks Elliott!